# How can a link be provided in Alert box to redirect to another page using flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I need to provide a link (like **Click here** to view.....) in a AlertBox that redirects to another page. Help needed...

Answer (score 0):

Then you may want to consider making something that isn't an alert box.  An alert box is just that, a box alerting you of something. I'm sure you could pound a square peg into a round hole, but I would rather take the easier route and make a custom component that looks like an alert box with an html link in it.

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom component extending `Panel`. Add a link `Label` to it. Than use `PopUpManager.addPopUp` to show your custom alert box.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom TitleWindow and style it to look like Alert box. Set header height 0 and you get rid of TitleWindow header. Use PopUpManager to popup your own Alert window.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you'll need to create a new Panel or TitleWindow and add your own link there.  Here's an example that should get you started:

**NewAlert.mxml**

```
            import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

            static public function show(text:String = null, title:String = 'Alert', modal:Boolean = true):NewAlert
            {
                var w:NewAlert = PopUpManager.createPopUp(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication, NewAlert, modal) as NewAlert;
                w.title = title;
                w.text = text;
                return ;
            }

            // Can be HTML text
            public function set text(value:String):void
            {
                if(value && value.length > 0)
                {
                    richTxt.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(value, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
                }
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:RichEditableText id="richTxt" 
                        editable="false" 
                        focusEnabled="false">
        <s:textFlow>
            <s:TextFlow>
                <s:p>
                    Default Text with Link: <s:a href="http://www.adobe.com">Adobe.com</s:a>
                </s:p>
            </s:TextFlow>
        </s:textFlow>
    </s:RichEditableText>
</s:TitleWindow>
```

From here, you can just do `NewAlert.show('some HTML content')` as long as the html text is properly formatted, it'll be good.